# How to Improve Performance of API Calls in Pandas DataFrame Loop?

Tags: python, apply

I have a DataFrame df_flights where each row represents input data for making an API call. The DataFrame is quite big (can be 1000 rows). For each row, I need to extract values from every column to make an API call, which returns a new row for a new DataFrame.

Here's a simplified version of my current approach:

```
# Initialize an empty DataFrame
df_bereik = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through each row of df_flights
for index, row in df_flights.iterrows(): 
    # Make an API call using values from the current row
    df = get_new_df(index, row, variable, token)
    
    # Merge the result DataFrame with df_bereik
    df_bereik = pd.concat([df_bereik, df], ignore_index=True)

def get_new_df(index, row, target_group, token):
    advertiser = row["advertiser"]
    product = row["product"]
    etc.

    df = call_api(variable, advertiser, product)

    #I also need to clean the api data
    df = clean_up(df, advertiser, product, variable, etc.)

    return df

def clean_up(df):
    do something
    return df
```

Now this is all very slow due to iterrows. But I can't seem to make something work that returns the same result and is faster. Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a sample input and desired output?

Comment: Hmm I don't think that is relevant. The input has info for the API call, like advertiser, product. The output is completly different information  and should be in a different dataframe. The API call returns multiple rows and columns for every input row.

Comment: You can experiment with asyncio to make paralell calls to the API. These calls probably take great amount of time. Additionally, you may want to first gather data from API and then do the cleanup on the whole dataset.